# Adding "X-Google-Sender-Auth" in email header to avoid email being marked dangerous

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, gmail

I have been trying to send messages using Google App Script using the [Gmail Message Send API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)

Here's the code:

```
  var yourEmailAddress = "testingemail@gmail.com";
  var myEmailAddress = "senderemail@gmail.com";
  var subject = "testing mail";
  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
  var htmlBody = '<html><body>' + '<h1>HI</h1>' + '</body></html>';

  var message = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
    'From: Jack Doe <' + myEmailAddress + '>\r\n' +
    'To: John Doe <' + yourEmailAddress + '>\r\n' +
    'Subject: ' + subject + '\r\n' +
    'Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundaryboundary\r\n\r\n' +
    '--boundaryboundary\r\n' +
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n' +
    htmlBody + "\r\n\r\n" +
    '--boundaryboundary--';

  console.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())

  var params = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "message/rfc822",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: message
  };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send", params);
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
```

The emails are being identified as being dangerous by the recipient's Gmail Client -
[Gmail identified email to be dangerous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taUkE.png)

Upon trying to check the email original code, I identified that the email lacks [`"X-Google-Sender-Auth"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRqKY.png), which is normally present in emails sent via some Mail Merge tools from Gmail.

How do we add this field when sending the email?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue with Gmail API .

Comment: I have updated the code snippet.

Comment: Using relevant tags ensure your question reaches the proper audience. Your question never reached the intended audience as you missed [google-apps-script] tag.